# Is there a way that we can declare the type from a different gql file?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-schema

I've been trying to make this one work. I am currently learning Apollo Server and GraphQL. I went to different documentations but I can't seem to find an answer. Here's what I am trying to do.

I have **usertypes.js** and here's the code snippet:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

const UserTypeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    _id: ID!,
    username: String!,
    password: String!,
  }
`;

module.exports = UserTypeDefs;
```

And on my **logintypes.js**:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');
const { UserTypeDefs } = require('./usertypes.js') 

const LoginTypeDefs = gql`
    type LoginResponse {
        user: UserTypeDefs.User //this is not working. :(
    }

    extend type Mutation {
        login(username: String!, password: String!): LoginResponse!
    }
`;


module.exports = LoginTypeDefs;
```

Any help is appreciated. I don't want to declare my *type User* again in my **logintypes.js** as much as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How do you define `not working`? Rather than redeclaring any types, as long as you create a single `executableSchema` composed of your `User` and `Login`, then there shouldn't be any errors as far as I understand. Here's an article to help understand how you can achieve this: https://blog.apollographql.com/modularizing-your-graphql-schema-code-d7f71d5ed5f2

Comment: I followed this link that you have provided and I was able to resolve my issue. I removed the `const { gql } = require('apollo-server');` from both of usertypes.js and logintypes.js then declare my typedefs as string instead of gql``; Thanks!

Comment: Happy to know you resolved it. Have fun

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to import the other module. Just refer to the type by name:

```
type LoginResponse {
  user: User
}
```

Then, when you create your `ApolloServer` instance, pass in the typeDefs as an array:

```
const userTypeDefs = require(...)
const loginTypeDefs = require(...)

const apollo = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: [userTypeDefs, loginTypeDefs],
  ...
})
```